# What is the StateChangeDate in a Publish Transaction?

Tags: publishing, publishtransaction

I'd like to get the date/time of when an item is published.  Is this represented in the StateChangeDate attribute of the PublishTransaction XML?

My PublishTransaction item xml is:

```
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:0-693-66560" Title="page86" Allow="24576" Deny="67108864" Icon="T64L0P0" 
ItemType="64" ItemID="tcm:5-86-64" State="1" StateChangeDate="2015-05-26T11:40:34" 
Publication="002 Web" PublicationTarget="Staging" ItemPath="\002 Web\Root" Action="0" 
ScheduleDate="" UserId="tcm:0-11-65552" User="DEV\Admin" Priority="4" Managed="0" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The StateChangeDate gets the date/time when the last state change occurred for the transaction. So it will tell you when the transactions current state is achieved.  And if the transaction is published successfully (means its in published state (6)), the property will give you the time when the item is published.

Comment: OK, so it is the publish or unpublish time....since those are the 'States' it is referring to, right?

Comment: Well, as in your xml the state is "1" means "waiting for publish". So yes in your case its publish time.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a full list of the Publish States here, http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-714ACA0C-264F-4C63-8C93-AFFDA95C3DA3